# How to connect to Microsoft Word's Blog Posting Mechanism

Tags: c#, ms-word, xml-rpc

I'm wondering if anyone knows where I can find documentation on how to integrate with Microsoft Word's new blog publishing service (example here - http://www.howtogeek.com/169119/how-to-create-a-blog-post-using-microsoft-word-2013/).  I'd like to create a custom connection for my blogging engine.  Based on the example it looks like it uses XMLRPC, but what I'm unclear of is if there some specific signature that the receiving web service method needs to implement.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Shawn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that you will find detail document for this.

There is product called "Windows Live Writer" and it also support same type of functionality. It is not something that MS Word do and it is provided by blog service.

It internally use XML-RPC api like bloggerAPI , wordpress api to connect and publish the blog item.

Hope this information help you.

Comment: Thanks, googling around for Windows Live Writer api helped me find these: 
a. http://www.matlus.com/metaweblog-api-c-library/
b. http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode55NotABlogALocalXMLRPCMetaWebLogEndpointThatLiesToWindowsLiveWriter.aspx